# How to send SharedPreferences from one Activity to another

Tags: android

I am trying to adapt this code http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/getting-started-complete-android-app.html for my quiz game.  I have downloaded http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ as suggested in the comment section of the link above.  I have my own db running on my device and I am using Eclipse and targeting Android 4.  All works.  What I cannot get to work is the SettingsActivity even though in my new db I have changed the difficulty ratings and made sure there are Easy, Medium and Hard.

When I leave the Settings on "Medium" difficulty the quiz game goes off without a hitch. When I change the Settings to "Easy" and then go back to menu and click play the game tells me it is stopping.

I am posting what I feel are the relevant code. I have not been able to find anything other than what is posted in the comment section of the link.

The SplashActivity:

```
private List<Question> getQuestionSetFromDb() throws Error {
        int diff = getDifficultySettings();
        Syste`enter code here`m.out.print("diff" + diff);
        //Log("diff" + diff);
        int numQuestions = getNumQuestions();
        DBHelper myDbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }
        List<Question> questions = myDbHelper.getQuestionSet(diff, numQuestions);
        myDbHelper.close();
        return questions;
    }

/**
     * Method to return the difficulty settings
     * @return
     */
    private int getDifficultySettings() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
        int diff = settings.getInt(Constants.DIFFICULTY, Constants.EASY);
        return diff;
    }
```

The SettingsActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        /**
         * set listener on update button
         */
        Button updateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        /**
         * Set selected button if saved
         */
        updateButtonWithPreferences();

    }


    /**
     * Method to update default check box
     */
    private void updateButtonWithPreferences() {
        RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.easySetting);
        RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.mediumSetting);
        RadioButton c3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.hardSetting);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
        int diff = settings.getInt(Constants.DIFFICULTY, Constants.MEDIUM);

        switch (diff)
        {
        case Constants.EASY : 
            c1.toggle();
            break;

        case Constants.MEDIUM : 
            c2.toggle();
            break;

        case Constants.EXTREME :
            c3.toggle();
            break;  
        }
    }





    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        /**
         * check which settings set and return to menu
         */
        if (!checkSelected())
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
            Editor e = settings.edit();
            e.putInt(Constants.DIFFICULTY, getSelectedSetting());
            e.commit();
            finish();
        }

    }


    /**
     * Method to check that a checkbox is selected
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    private boolean checkSelected() {
        RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.easySetting);
        RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.mediumSetting);
        RadioButton c3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.hardSetting);
        return (c1.isChecked() || c2.isChecked() || c3.isChecked());
    }


    /**
     * Get the selected setting 
     */
    private int getSelectedSetting() {
        RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.easySetting);
        RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.mediumSetting);
        if (c1.isChecked())
        {
            return Constants.EASY;
        }
        if (c2.isChecked())
        {
            return Constants.MEDIUM;
        }

        return Constants.EXTREME;
    }

}
```

The rest of the code works fine include the new questions that I put into the db so I will keep the code posting at this unless someone request anything more.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Terry

Comment: if there is an error post the stacktrace

Comment: Just now working through tutorials on debugging. Placed breakpoint on "diff" (calling the difficulty) and on calling updateButtonWithPreferences() but my experience on this front is limited but will continue to work through and gain the knowledge. Any advice in this regard?

Comment: tyczj, here is the stack trace after choosing the "Easy" button and running the "Play" button: android.app.ActivityThread@42c2a0d8
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
com.igogeo.android.chuck.QuestionActivity@42d325f8
ActivityInfo{42d31c68 com.igogeo.android.chuck.QuestionActivity}
ComponentInfo{com.igogeo.android.chuck/com.igogeo.android.chuck.QuestionActivity}
ActivityRecord{42d324f8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42d31c08 {com.igogeo.android.chuck/com.igogeo.android.chuck.QuestionActivity}}
null

Answer (score 1):

Use this to use application scope shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)
```

In place of:
     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);

Comment: In place of what/where ak?